# Deferred lighting ignore viewport rect?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on an Unity project. I want to render two cameras on one render texture  similar with the picture below[image].

But when I set both camera's render path to "Deferred lighting". The camera ignore viewport rect. But when I set the render path to "forward". Viewport rect took effect immediately.
Any one got an idea why this happen?
Thx.